# Use NPTL while keeping glibc with linuxthreads

Tags: linux, glibc, nptl, linuxthreads

I would like to know if it is possible to test a specific binary with nptl instead of linuxthreads which is embedded in my glibc. I don't want to recompile the glibc because it is the one provided with my specific hardware/software and I don't want to break everything. I just want to be able to test this implementation and to see what could be the gain

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to recompile the glibc

If your glibc was compiled with linuxthreads, and not nptl, then obviously you can't use it to test a binary with nptl.

Your choices are:

1. Use some other (newer) system that has nptl-enabled glibc, or
2. Build a separate nptl-enabled version of glibc, and use *it*, e.g.

   cd glibc-2.15
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/glibc-nptl && make && sudo make install

   # now run the binary using newly-built glibc:
    /usr/glibc-nptl/lib/ld-2.15.so /path/to/binary

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).